# wordpress theme not activating

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

> whenever i activate any theme on my wordpress, i got this error. can anyone help me how to resolve this error?

checking the error.log file i got this error in that file.

```
unexpected '<' in /tmp/theme_temp_setupOG3lLA on line 2
```

can anyone tell me how to resolve it???

[image: Error after activating theme]

Comment: what is in this file `theme_temp_setupOG3lLA` ?

Comment: try to install wordpress from scratch.

Comment: @danielefois installed twice except wp-content folder

Comment: @mmm there is no file with such name in tmp folder

Comment: Try to enable WP_DEBUG to true in wp-config.php file. And reactivate again to see if any errors.